# process.argv shows empty for babel transpiled codes

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-core

I am trying to achieve es2015 features on "node version 8.4.0". That's why I am using babel to transpile my es6 to node compatible code.

I am trying to run `node bundle.js arguments` and using process.argv returns an empty array. where running `node index.js arguments` gives the arguments list.

Using docker: `Linux 37901bca5bc7 4.10.0-041000-generic #201702191831 SMP Sun Feb 19 23:33:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Node packages:

`"babel-core": "^6.23.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",`

To bundle the code I am using webpack.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: es6 **is** a node compatible code... Inventing another wheel?
 http://node.green/ . And using webpack to bundle node code... Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Comment: Agree for webpack part with @smnbbrv. But about babel and es6, it's still great according to the fact node.js do not support `import` yet which is one the most useful thing in a project

Comment: @smnbbrv, I said I want to achieve es6 features on node v8.4.0. imports are not available on node. so I am trying to transpile that code to ES5.

Comment: I am trying to build a cli tool that will take the arguments from terminal, npm run scriptname argument. when I try the bundled file, argv is empty. if I try the actual file, index.js in this case. gets arguments passed correctly. is my way of solving the issue wrong? how can I solve it otherwise?

Comment: Opinion: While I think ES6 modules are great, if you are only developing for Node, which not stick with CommonJS until Node natively supports ES6 modules? I don't think that having to use webpack just for module support is worth the hassle.